# How to select a column value depending if id is even or odd

Tags: mysql

having a table structure of id and a name:

```
create table Mytable (
      id integer not null,
      name varchar(30) not null,
      unique(id)
  );



insert into Mytable (id,name) values
     (1 , 'one'),
     (2 , 'two'),
     (3 , 'three'),
     (4 , 'four'),
     (6 , 'six');
```

How may I get a mix of even and odd rows in a result table like:

```
  even | odd
  -----------
  null   one           '0 is not in Mytable so it puts null value
  two    three
  four   null          '5 and 6 are not in Mytable so it puts null value
  six    null
```

I was trying to first get the following as a template and use it later as
a dictionary:

```
SELECT MIN(id-1) as id,MAX(id-1) as col
  FROM Mytable
  GROUP BY FLOOR((id+1)/2);
```

I get:

```
id  col
0   1        
2   3
5   5
```

But I do not know how to continue

Comment: So you want a MySQL query? Which flavour? <=5.7 or > 8?

Comment: What happens if there is no row for id = 8 and 9. Will you show `null, null` (both columns as null) or just ignore that row

Comment: yes, will show null,null

Comment: Please run `Select Version();` and let us the result of this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL Version <= 5.7, You can use the below query

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.id % 2 = 0 THEN name END) AS even,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.id % 2 = 1 THEN name END) AS odd
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable) AS maxid,
        @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
        (SELECT IF((@rn * 2) <= maxid, @rn, NULL)) AS rid
    FROM 
        mytable
    JOIN 
        (SELECT @rn := -1) AS var 
) AS t
JOIN 
    mytable m ON FLOOR(m.id/2) = t.rid
GROUP BY rid;
```

**Result 1:**

> ```
> even | odd  
> :--- | :----
> null | one  
> two  | three
> four | null 
> six  | null
> ```

**Demo 1:** 
[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=82b1958724fdc658d84278215585e73d)

---

**Query 2:**
     After confirmation based on @Madhur Bhaiya comment. If there is no row for id = 8 and 9 then it will show `null, null`.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.id % 2 = 0 THEN name END) AS even,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.id % 2 = 1 THEN name END) AS odd
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        (SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable) AS maxid,
        @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
        (SELECT IF((@rn * 2) <= maxid, @rn, NULL)) AS rid
    FROM 
        (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t
    JOIN
        (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t2
    JOIN 
        (SELECT @rn := -1) var -- currently it will return 1..100, if needed more add joins based on your needs
) AS t
LEFT JOIN 
    mytable m ON FLOOR(m.id/2) = t.rid
GROUP BY rid HAVING rid IS NOT NULL;
```

**Result 2:**

> ```
> even    | odd   
> :------ | :-----
> null    | one   
> two     | three 
> four    | null  
> six     | null  
> null    | null  
> null    | eleven
> null    | null  
> null    | null  
> sixteen | null
> ```

**Demo 2:** 
[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=56925562c9baf1c42090bdd97d09733f)

---

For MySQL Version > 8.0, You can use @Nick query but if you need `null, null` like **Result 2** mentioned for <= v5.7 then add `LEFT JOIN` with `ORDER BY` clause.

**Query:**

```
with recursive maxid as (
    select max(id) as id from Mytable)
, cte as (
select 0 as rid
union all
select rid + 1 
from cte
cross join maxid
where (rid + 1) * 2 <= maxid.id)
select max(case when m.id % 2 = 0 then name end) as even,
       max(case when m.id % 2 = 1 then name end) as odd
from cte
left join Mytable m on floor(m.id / 2) = cte.rid
group by rid order by rid;
```

**Result:**

> ```
> even    | odd   
> :------ | :-----
> null    | one   
> two     | three 
> four    | null  
> six     | null  
> null    | null  
> null    | eleven
> null    | null  
> null    | null  
> sixteen | null
> ```

**Demo:** [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=17a752a32894b7ecfd0a5a3b37565491)

**Credits:** Thanks to @Nick, @Madhur Bhaiya for the fiddle and the logic used to create this query.

Comment: Quite comprehensive answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `CTE` based query that will work in SQL Server and MySQL > v8.0 (with the addition of the keyword `recursive` before `maxid`). It generates a list of rows that encompasses the pairs of `MyTable` values (in the sample, this is `0,1,2,3`) and then JOINs that to `Mytable` to extract the even/odd column values:

```
with maxid as (
    select max(id) as id from Mytable)
, cte as (
select 0 as rid
union all
select rid + 1 
from cte
cross join maxid
where (rid + 1) * 2 <= maxid.id)
select max(case when m.id % 2 = 0 then name end) as even,
       max(case when m.id % 2 = 1 then name end) as odd
from cte
join Mytable m on m.id / 2 = cte.rid
group by rid
```

Output:

```
even    odd
        one
two     three
four    
six
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=350ab41a3f5cbf2a23148833090befe7)